# VBoxService not starting in Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-preview

Managed to get Windows 10 running as a VirtualBox guest on Linux fine. However the 'Guest Additions Service' VBoxService will not start and there is no additional info in the Windows Event Logs.

Does anyone know the solution or how to debug this issue?

Comment: It sounds like the service isn't compatible with Windows 10.  You will have to wait until it is.  There really isn't anything to debug from a normal user perspective.

Comment: FWIW, Windows 10 TP runs poorly on my decent-spec machine; it runs better on VMware Player.

Comment: @happy_soil - If you are still running Windows 10 Technical Preview that would be the reason it runs poorly.  The current released version is called Windows 10 Insider Preview.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, that's what I meant. I'm on build 10122. I wasn't aware of the new naming scheme until now.